# What are the most essential modifiers for shaping light?

Tags: flash, lighting, off-camera-flash, studio-setup, lighting-modifiers

I don't have a studio so I mostly shoot outside on locations, or for practice in my small room.
I see some pictures that they have shaped and directed the light so well. For example a violin where half of it is in dark and half in light, or a face where the two sides are in dark and the middle of the face in light (see example below).

How can I do those things and shape the light? As for light modifiers and some tools here is what I have.  Is it gear I am missing or is it skills and practice?

Tools:

- Flashes: Two SB-910 for TTL and a LumoPro LP180 for Manual
- Radio Triggers: Pocket Wizard Plus III
- Light meter: Sekonic 478 DR

Modifiers:

- Two shoot through umbrellas, small size I think 20"
- One snoot grid, Rogue 3-in-1 thingy. ( I don't like it, hard to aim and use,  do you have better recommendations for this?)
- One Joe McNally EzyBox HotShoe SoftBox
- LumiQuest SoftBox III
- Some color gels.

[image: Sample I would like to be able to produce]

Comment: Some example photos would be good. It may well be you are seeing examples of light painting: a long exposure in a dark room, with the object being lit with a flashlight in specific areas.

Comment: no it is not light painting. I'll try to find examples but with some imagination power you can imagine the type of pics I am asking about :)

Comment: Is that photo yours? Or a example of what you want to achive?

Comment: @Rafael quick Google image search of an example I like to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just me, but I'd say, **you're missing the skills and practice, not the tools**.

Your gear is a pretty good basic three-light setup (assuming you just didn't feel like listing the stands and swivels).  You have umbrellas, and a 24" softbox, and while they might be a little small, they're still pretty decent-sized.

The main thing you have to learn here is that lighting is as much about where the light *doesn't* go as where it does.  Spatial separation is tough in a small studio space, but it's often required to keep lights from "polluting" each other.  And you probably really need to practice a bit more with gobos/flags/grids/barndoors to limit the light spread. And maybe a bit more reading to begin to learn how to reverse-engineer lighting and how to read the light placement from the shadows.

The basic textbook on lighting is *[Light, Science and Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415719402)*, now in its 5th edition.  And the main website fount of off-camera lighting knowledge is [the Strobist](http://www.strobist.com).  You may also be able to find a good class or workshop in your area.  David Hobby also has his video course on line at Lynda.com, and Zach Arias sells downloadable videos on off-camera lighting basics.

Lighting is not a subject everyone can instinctively figure out on their own.  Some folks are phenoms and can. But the rest of us need some help.  I read the Strobist for more than two years, bought all the gear, and it never "clicked" for me, until I took a local hands-on workshop. Consider getting some instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know if that is what you want to achieve or a result of a photo of yours you want to improve.

I will only comment that for low key photos probably the shoot through umbrellas are not the best option because they spill a lot of light.

I'm imagining the violin and the face photo, and I suppose you want more contrast, like the dark side of the face as pure black.

As you probably have some light spilling, and therefore bouncing on a far wall you probably need to have a black matte cardboard or a black cloth to absorb that light. Here is a diagram.

[image]

Or try to buy a softbox, probably with some grid. The bigger the softbox, the better. But the size is relative. There are some interesting shapes: thin, rectangular, square. For portrait photography I would aim for a 30x20in. For close ups you can use a smaller one and for full body you probably need a bigger one.

The power of your flashes is affected by the size of the softbox. As I think you are using speedlights, probably need a smaller one, or an array of flashes inside the softbox.

Another way to "sharpen"  the light is moving away your source of light.

Comment: thanks, so no strip lighting needed? I have that SoftBox from Joe McNally series called EzyBox SoftBox HotShoe so I think I should get a "grid" or "strip" than can go on top of that softbox...

Comment: Oh, good. Play with the distances, play with the position and play with the angle. If you need mask your softbox with black cloth. You dont need to have a striplight, you can *make* one if you need.